# How to create an array from a CSV file using PHP but NOT using fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv

I have a file named csvFile.csv

First row is:

> Id;fechaAlta;DNI;CUIT;Apellido;Nombre;Direccion;CP;Tel1;Tel2;Sexo;mail;Ficha

Second row is:

> 3;2008-10-25;33360466;27333604665;PEREZ;SABRINA;RIVADAVIA 4543 Piso: 3  Depto:  A Barrio:  PARQUE LICEO Codigo Postal: 5000 Localidad: CORDOBA;5000;192772656;47881752;F;sperez@hotmail.com;342

I need a PHP function that allows me to have control of each element in each row.

Now, I use the function:

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    print_r( $line_of_text);
}
```

Then I get the following result:

```
Array 
( 
[0] => Array ( 

[0] => Id;fechaAlta;DNI;CUIT;Apellido;Nombre;Direccion;CP;Tel1;Tel2;Sexo;mail;Ficha ) 

[1] => Array ( [0] => 3;2008-10-25;11660466;27116604665;PEREZ;SABRINA;COLON 43 Piso: 4 Depto: B Barrio: CENTRO  Codigo Postal: 5000 Localidad: CORDOBA;5000;158882656;4111752;F;sperez@hotmail.com;342 )
)
```

But I need a result as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Id
            [1] => fechaAlta
            [2] => DNI
            [3] => CUIT
    #

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2008-10-25
            [2] => 11660466
            [3] => 27116604665
#
        )
```

How should be the function to get the result above?

Comment: Have you checked the parameters for `fgetcsv` in the manual?!

Comment: In what way do you want "control of each element in each row"? Is it just a change of separator?

Comment: You are using `fgetcsv` incorrectly. However, if you really do not want to use fgetcsv you can use `fgets` to get a single line at a time, then use the `explode()` function to explode each line into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need another function; just use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) properly - the default separator is a `,` and your file has `;` as the separator, so you need to tell fgetcsv() that little fact:

```
$line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ';');
```

then it will work for you

Comment: We need a canonical for: "I use function X, but it doesn't work properly what do I do?" and with the answer "RTM about the function with which you have a problem/question.". That would make life much easier ;)